# Cannot expose port from container to host, using PHP static webserver

Tags: php, docker, dockerfile

I have this multi-stage build in a Dockerfile:

```
## Stage 1
FROM node:9 as builder

RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install sudo
RUN echo "newuser ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL" >> /etc/sudoers

RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash newuser
USER newuser
RUN mkdir -p /home/newuser/app
WORKDIR /home/newuser/app

RUN sudo chown -R $(whoami) $(npm config get prefix)/lib
RUN npm set progress=false
RUN npm config set depth 0
RUN npm cache clean --force

COPY dist .

## Stage 2
FROM php:5.6.30

RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install sudo
RUN echo "newuser ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL" >> /etc/sudoers

RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash newuser
USER newuser
RUN mkdir -p /home/newuser/app
WORKDIR /home/newuser/app

COPY --from=builder /home/newuser/app /home/newuser/app

RUN ls -a /home/newuser/app

CMD ["php", "-S", "localhost:3000"]
```

the image build successfully, using:

```
  docker build -t x .
```

Then I run it with:

```
   docker run -p 3000:3000 x
```

but when I go to localhost:3000 on the host machine, I don't get a response. The webpage is blank.

Does anyone know why that might happen?

I also tried:

```
CMD ["sudo", "php", "-S", "localhost:80"]
```

and

```
  docker run -p 3000:80 x
```

and a few other variations, still nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why the PHP static server wasn't working, but I got it working with Node.js static server package:

```
FROM node:9 as builder

RUN apt-get update && \
      apt-get -y install sudo

RUN echo "newuser ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL" >> /etc/sudoers

RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash newuser
USER newuser
RUN mkdir -p /home/newuser/app
WORKDIR /home/newuser/app

RUN sudo chown -R $(whoami) $(npm config get prefix)/lib
RUN sudo chown -R $(whoami) $(npm config get prefix)/lib/node_modules
RUN sudo chown -R $(whoami) $(npm config get prefix)/bin
RUN sudo chown -R $(whoami) $(npm config get prefix)/share
RUN sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/lib

RUN npm set progress=false
RUN npm config set depth 0
RUN npm cache clean --force

COPY dist .

RUN npm install -g http-server

ENTRYPOINT ["http-server", "."]
```

you build it like so:

```
docker build -t x .
```

and then run it like so:

```
docker run -p 3000:8080 x
```